# Dockerfileに記述しているシェルスクリプト内で環境変数を設定したい。

Tags: docker, rbenv

rbenv をビルドして、rubyをインストールしようと思っています。

ubuntu16.04のイメージを使用して、rbenvをgithubからとってきて、ビルドし以下のようにして、rbenv の初期化を実行しようとしたところ、`RUN rbenv global 2.3.3` のところでエラーになります。

```
RUN echo 'eval "$(rbenv init -)" >> /root/.profile
RUN . /root/.profile
RUN rbenv install 2.3.3
RUN rbenv global 2.3.3
RUN ruby -v
```

調べていくと、`eval "$(rbenv init -)"` で設定している環境変数が設定されていないようでした。ENVを使用すれば環境変数が設定できることは知っているのですが、今回はrbenvが自動で実行するスクリプト内で設定されているので、ENVは使えないのではないか？と思っています。なにか回避策はありますでしょうか。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dockerfile の中の RUN コマンドは、それぞれ別のシェルで実行されたはずです。なので、ひとつのシェルコマンドにしてしまえば、正しく動くと考えられます。

```
RUN echo 'eval "$(rbenv init -)" >> /root/.profile && \
    . /root/.profile && \
    rbenv install 2.3.3 && \
    rbenv global 2.3.3 && \
    ruby -v
```